# Error importing XML to InDesign

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

I'm have an XML file from client that I need to import to Indesign but image *href* in the file are not in the correct format for Indesign

> (it is like; image href = "imagename")

so I need to correct them to

> image href = "file:///imagename.tif"

but after I finished with the editing and try to import the file into InDesign, there is this error "Encoding specified in the XML declaration is incorrect" I don't know what is wrong with it. Please help.

here is the document declaration in the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2007, v.4002-->
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd" [
]>
<!--DITAJoinStart Foreword=GUID-7ACB990C-858C-40C1-89D6-74B409EA2C1E=2=en=.xml-->
<?ish ishref="GUID-7ACB990C-858C-40C1-89D6-74B409EA2C1E" version="2" lang="en"?>
<topic id="GUID-7ACB990C-858C-40C1-89D6-74B409EA2C1E" xml:lang="en">
<title id="GUID-77E06CAF-CA60-49AE-8621-C5EFC5EC1A17">Foreword</title>
<body/>
<!--DITAJoinEnd-->
```

**I don't have the topic.dtd file (the client didn't give me)

P.S I have only basic knowledge of coding and XML is new for me.

Comment: Did you try Changing UTF-16 to UTF-8?

Comment: yes i did. I tried changed it to UTF-8 but when I tried to import it to Indesign, the not well-formed error appeared

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to affirm anything with so few data. However, in your sample, the topic node which seems to be your root is open but not closed appearently. That's a non valid structure.

Try this :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2007, v.4002-->
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd" [
]>
<!--DITAJoinStart Foreword=GUID-7ACB990C-858C-40C1-89D6-74B409EA2C1E=2=en=.xml-->
<?ish ishref="GUID-7ACB990C-858C-40C1-89D6-74B409EA2C1E" version="2" lang="en"?>
<topic id="GUID-7ACB990C-858C-40C1-89D6-74B409EA2C1E" xml:lang="en">
<title id="GUID-77E06CAF-CA60-49AE-8621-C5EFC5EC1A17">Foreword</title>
<body/>
<!--CLOSING THE topic NODE-->
</topic>
<!--DITAJoinEnd-->
```